# Can't build even a simple program in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I have just switched from Python to C++ for implementing Data Structures and Algorithms. I found that Sublime Text 3 was quiet powerful. I installed it, added my Mingw-64 compiler to the path and also added a "build system". I hoped it would be suffice to build and run any basic C++ program. But when I run

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   cout<<n<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I know, there is some problem either in the build part or the compiler settings. I tried different compilers, from code blocks to independent Mingw-64 compiler without any success. In the past, I have used Code Blocks, it never required me to create an exe file or reference it. If I restart the program, it will show permission denied error which I know why it occurs.

Here is the error:

> The system cannot find the file G:\Programming\C++\second.exe.
>   [Finished in 15.0s with exit code 1]
>
> [shell_cmd: g++ "G:\Programming\C++\second.cpp" -o
>   "G:\Programming\C++/second" && "G:\Programming\C++/second"] [dir:
>   G:\Programming\C++] [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production
>   Server\R2015a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production
>   Server\R2015a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production
>   Server\R2015a\polyspace\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0\mingw32\bin;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\Anaconda3;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;G:\Microsoft
>   VS
>   Code\bin;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\80LM0141IH\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;";C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin";C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Graphviz2.34\bin;]

Comment: You build `second` and try to run `second.exe`. This is a reason.

Comment: Note that it's easier to diagnose Sublime build issues if you include the `sublime-build` that you're using to perform the build.

Comment: And what should I do, not to call second.exe. I press ctrl+shift+b to execute the cpp file.

Comment: Use a manual and learn build and run settings in Sublime Text.

Comment: You are right. However No official document has a link to this type of stuff. I checked this http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html on the website. Here too, there is no such reference to any useful material.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before we start, you need to **make sure that you have installed a C++ compiler and configured its path correctly**. Make sure that you can invoke `g++` command in the command line.

I see from your code that you need input from the standard input. Sublime Text's console can not accept input. So that maybe that is the problem. You need to run this program in a terminal

Try to replace your build system with following settings:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++, source.cpp, source.cc, source.cxx",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run in Terminal",

            "linux": {
                "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && xterm -e '${file_path}/${file_base_name} && echo && echo Press ENTER to continue && read line && exit'",
                // "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}&& echo && echo Press ENTER to continue && read line && exit\"'", // for gnome-terminal 
                // "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && xterm -e '${file_path}/${file_base_name}; bash'", // for xterm
                // "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && xterm -hold -e ${file_path}/${file_base_name}", // for xterm
                // "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && konsole --hold -e ${file_path}/./${file_base_name}", // for konsole

            },

            "windows":{
                "shell_cmd":   "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && start cmd /k  $file_base_name "
                // "shell_cmd":   "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && start \"$file_base_name\" call $file_base_name"
            },

            "osx":{
                "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && xterm -e '${file_path}/${file_base_name} && echo && echo Press ENTER to continue && read line && exit'",
            },

            "shell": true,
        },
    ]
}
```

Press `Ctrl + Shift + B` and choose `C++ - Run in Terminal`. It will compile and run the program in your cmd.
[image]

I can run your code snippet correctly in my environment. Let me know if you encounter any problem.

[image]

Comment: Oh, After so much looking, It finally worked. There is a need of many many programmers like you sir! Thanks.

Comment: If my answer solves your question, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I ran this on ubuntu, but this does not pop up the terminal. Any reasons for that?

Comment: Do you have `xterm` or other GUI terminal installed on your system? You have to choose from the different options which suit you.

Comment: I installed both xterm and gnome. I even installed konsole, the executable would not open for xterm and konsole. It does open for 1st command for "linux" the terminal wont pop up, and same for gnome

Comment: For Xterm it shows this: bash: /media/ashish/New: No  such file or directory. So I should manually create a directory there? The thing is it shows permission denied to create a dir there because I have dual booted windows with linux. I do have admin privilages on Ubuntu

Comment: I have tested the build system on my CentOS, it is working fine. It may have something to do with your settings? Can you manually run the program using xterm? for example, `xterm -e './test && echo && echo Press ENTER to continue && read line && exit'` (replace `test` with the actual program name).

Comment: Ohk, I fixed it, when you said, it was working for you. The problem was I was saving my program in a dir, which was not accessible by sublime text. It is accessible via GUI on ubuntu and terminal, not by sublime text. Now it is fixed. I highly appreciate your concern. Thanks:)

Comment: How to run the code in build terminal of sublime text itself without opening new terminal?