# Error while compiling even easy C++ programs in Sublime text 3

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, sublimetext3

I have installed the Sublime text 3 and I want to compile C++ programs in it. I referred to [this](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2017/04/how-to-run-c-and-c-program-in-sublime-text.html) article for making Sublime compatible for compiling C++ programs but I kept getting the following error

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\USER\Downloads\CCDSAP\sublime/test1.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 1.9s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ -std=c++11 -Wall "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\CCDSAP\sublime\test1.cpp" -o "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\CCDSAP\sublime/test1" && "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\CCDSAP\sublime/test1"]
[dir: C:\Users\USER\Downloads\CCDSAP\sublime]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Android;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps]
```

After facing this error I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539509/cant-build-even-a-simple-program-in-sublime-text-3) question on StackOverflow and I again tried with the build code given in the above link. But it is again giving me the same error.

Note that I am able to compile and run programs through CodeBlocks IDE very smoothly and I am also able to invoke the g++ command through the command line on Windows. Can someone please help?
Thank you.

Comment: Could it be that you are running the program? Close it and then try again to compile it!

Comment: "_cannot open output file C:\Users\USER\Downloads\CCDSAP\sublime/test1.exe: Permission denied_" Did you, by any chance, forget to close the application, before recompiling it?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I was not able to run the program even once on Sublime so there was no running window that I could close and also I made sure that I closed all the Codeblocks running windows before even opening Sublime text 3 for compiling the program.

Comment: @user1712 Open Task manager. Is "test1.exe" running?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Ok so even after closing the test1.exe was running in the task manager. I ended the task and restarted Sublime text but still I am getting the same error :(

Comment: @user1712 Did you close all instances of it? The process might be ran multiple times.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yes, I closed all of them

Comment: Then try to delete the .exe file and compile again.

Comment: @user1712 In that case, I cannot help you. Typical reason for such an error, during linking, is if some process is holding a handle to the file. Which, in the case of .exe is, typically, that it is running (or, alternatively, that the antivirus software is preventing you to overwrite it). One could see, which process holds a handle to it, with tools such as Process Explorer. But apart from that: there's nothing more one can recommend with information provided.

Comment: Thank you guys, It started working perfectly fine after I deleted the .exe files from the working directory :)

Comment: Then I will turn my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are permission problems, but the application is not running, then try to delete the .exe file.

Comment: Any idea how I can grant Sublime those permissions?

Comment: You should actually always have the permission to overwrite a file that you have created yourself. Do you run some applications as another user? Or do you have special file system permissions settings? This seems mor to be a Windows problem than a C++ problem.

Comment: I don't use any such applications and also have a single user on my windows. Can you drop a link here that I can refer to to solve my problem (sorry I tried searching a lot but couldn't find any). Thanks a lot btw for solving a huge problem of mine :)

Comment: I am sorry, I have no more idea. Someone who is more familiar with Windows might be able to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that your program is already running.

It cannot be replaced by a new version if it is running.

You should close it before proceeding.

Comment: I was not able to run the program even once on Sublime so there was no running window that I could close and also I made sure that I closed all the Codeblocks running windows before even opening Sublime text 3 for compiling the program