# Using Sublime Text 3 for C++ giving permission denied?

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I have a problem with my Sublime Text 3 running C++ in the console.

I  pointed my `PATH` in my computer settings to the directory of my compiler for C++ and created a custom build script to run it in Sublime Text 3. For the most part it runs my code but after a couple of runs it gives me an error:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\obier\Desktop\C++ Projects\HelloWorld\SublimeNewHelloWorld/HelloWorld.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

I'm not sure what is going on.

Here is the custom Sublime Text 3 custom-build code I am using to compile it:

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
]
}
```

If any of ya'll have any good user friendly programs ya'll can suggest that might work better than using Sublime Text 3 than feel free to leave them.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages.
"[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"
"[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
"[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". FYI, asking us for recommendations is off-topic and made your question too broad. Please remove that. It's important to write concise and clear questions; Sticking to the important information is the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the shell command you used, it is depending on the OS.

Also check the file permissions because the file may not executable.

Also see "[Can't build even a simple program in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539509/cant-build-even-a-simple-program-in-sublime-text-3/50543811#50543811)".

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you i do really appreciate it. I'm not sure how i didn't come across that. I'm sorry for asking such a dumb question haha i just couldn't wrap my head around it. I have replaced it and so far it is working good. before it would run 1 time and then give the permission denied error. I have ran it a solid 20 times so far with no errors. I appreciate it alot.